# What WCF logging should I enable to help track down why a channel is being faulted?

Tags: .net, wcf, logging

The WCF channel is somehow getting into the faulted state in the client, what WCF logging show I enable to help track down the reason?

How do I enable the given logging from code?  (The channel etc is setup in code rather than a config file on each side)

---

Edit:  Both sides are Winforms applications, so I don’t have a web.config file, but I do have a app.config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add the logging in code.
On both the service (web.config) and the client (app.config) add this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
     initializeData="c:\logs\logfilename.svclog"/>
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

You should use the Service Trace Viewer (SvcTraceViewer.exe, included in SDK v6.0a) to view the files.

Comment: thanks, unlike log4net, system.diagnostics seems not to create the folders, therefore the above did not work for me until I create a c:\logs folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can still enable logging from web.config using system.diagnostics element (even if your channel was setup in code).

here are some msdn links: [(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) [(2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)

You can also have a look > [here](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/06/15/silverlight-and-wcf-wcf-logs-and-debugging/) < for step by step walkthrough.

Comment: sorry I did not say, both sides are Winforms applications, so I don’t have a web.config file, but I do have a app.config file.

Comment: you can do the same in app.config

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a shot in the dark, but this may be more of a debugging issue than a logging one.

You may need to check that your connections are being closed or pooled correctly. I use netstat from the command line to keep track of the open connections to the service to verify that connections are closed when I think they should be.